# REST htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest

I'm developing a PHP script which uses REST API. The request from client goes to

```
http://.../api/cart
```

I have a directory api/cart/ and a script index.php in it.

When client tries to request `http://.../api/cart` server redirects it to `http://.../api/cart/` (which is right, by the way) but it returns 300 response. But i need him to receive "200 OK"

What should I do? Maybe write some specific .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mod_negotiation thing, it depends on what other kind of stuff you have in your directories. Here, mod_negotiation sees a couple of things that the `/api/cart` request can map to, and it lets the user-agent know. You could try messing with multiviews and/or the mod_dir (to prevent the redirect). So maybe something like this in the `/api/` directory:

```
Options -Multiviews
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /api/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have created an .htaccess file and now it shows me 404 Error, what should I do?